# How to cache map service in different screen resolution using ArcGIS server 10.1

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-server, cache

I want to cache a map service to use tile map in my project .The problem is that i have some clients with different screen resolution . When i cache the map service and use anti-aliasing the best resolution and anti aliasing show in my screen resolution and in another clients the quality of map is not good.The screen resolution of clients are very different for example the screen resolution of my computer is 1920 * 1080 but on of the clients screen resolution is 5600 * 3150 screen. How can i manage caching process in different screen resolution ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is not in the "resolution" as size X x Y but in the "resolution" as DPI (dots per inch): you have (for example) 96 DPI (standard) on your screen and the clients have higher DPI on their screens. This resolution is controlled by DPI parameter of your service cache.

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Available_map_cache_properties/015400000414000000/ - the description of cache parameters.

Be aware: if you use the service on the device with different DPI you will get wrong scale. So you'll need to create different caches (services) for different devices.

Comment: Thanks @gnevan . How to change 96 DPI to another DPI . the default is 96 and i can't change that

Comment: Possibly you cannot change the DPI if the cache is already created. Try creating a new service with a new cache.

Comment: DPI is depends on screen resolution and diagonal size.default DPI is 96 but if you calculate DPI using DPI calculator for another Computers ,you can find different DPI's . Is there any way to cache a service in  server and cilents use the cache without any problems ?

Comment: I don't understand your question.